# Using Spring HTTP invoker between difference versions of spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a server which uses spring 2.5.6 and currently my client spring mvc application are also using same version 2.5.6. I use httpinvoker for the connection between the two. I want to update and benefit of spring mvc 3, but I can not do anything with the server.

My questions is:

1. Will it work to use a different version of spring on the web-application than on the server-side?
2. And can this have side-effects that can cause problems?